# How to allow access to members of an LDAP-group via apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ldap

I am trying to allow members of a certain LDAP-group into a site I'm hosting via Apache. I've read the documentaion on this, but as I have lacking LDAP skills, I could not determine how to accomplish this.

I have the following LDAP structure for the group:

```
dn: cn=icinga,ou=Groups,dc=mydomain,dc=no
objectClass: groupOfUniqeNames
objectClass: top
uniqeMember: uid=someuser,ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=no
uniqeMember: ..... <more of these>
```

My top level looks like this:

```
dn: dc=mydomain,dc=no
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
dc: mydomain
o: mydomain
```

So, what I've tried is this Apacehe-configruation:

```
AuthName "Icinga Access"
AuthType Basic

AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://myldapserver/ou=Groups,dc=mydomain,dc=no?uid"
AuthLDAPBindDN "MYBINDDN"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "XXXXXX"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

require ldap-group cn=icinga
```

And, it doesn't work, because, obviously I'm doing it wrong.. However, I did manage to auth with LDAP when using `ou=People` in the `AuthLDAPURL` directive, and `require ldap-user user otheruser foo` to accomplish this before, but that doesn't scale too well...

Comment: Oh! I fixed it! Changed the `AuthLDAPURL` back to `ou=People`, set the `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative` to `on`, and entered `require ldap-group cn=icinga,ou=Groups,dc=mydomain,dc=no` And voilla!

In addition I figured out that Apache is caching the LDAP entries, so it will not detect changes in the `uniqueMember`. So, i turned the caching off with `LDAPCacheEntries 0`

Comment: Please provide your own answer to this question and accept it when able to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. **This is not a forum.** Answers to questions go in the Answer section below, not as comments, and not as edits to the question.